# Merging multiple lines in sed, awk

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I have a following data set. A section with titles and section with subtitle. Each section has multiple lines, both section have same number of lines. I can print a symbol at an end or beginning of each line, which can be different in each section - in the example ^, %.

```
title^
another title^
other title^
one more title^
(... continues)
subtitle%
other subtitle%
some subtitle%
one more subtitle%
(... continues)
```

And I want to output it as

```
title subtitle 
another title other subtitle 
other title some subtitle
one more title one more subtitle
```

Basically I want to join 1st title with 1st subtitle on one line, then another line with 2nd title and 2nd subtitle.

Would this be possible in sed, awk ?

Comment: is that content of a single file? also be specific on the example `line 1` is too general provided that the file doesnt actually contains `line 1` as such

Comment: no, those are multiple lines - just like it is shown

Comment: I have updated my example to be more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a combination of `paste`, `grep` and `sed`:

```
$ paste <(grep "\^$" file | sed -e 's/\^$//')   <(grep "\%$" file | sed -e 's/\%$//')
title   subtitle
another title   other subtitle
other title some subtitle
one more title  one more subtitle
```

Explanation:

1. `paste` : merges two files
2. `<()`   : Bash process substitution, basically creates a file descriptor containing the output of the command inside `()`
3. `grep "\^$" file | sed -e 's/\^$//'`: select lines ending with `^` and delete it with sed
4. `grep "\%$" file | sed -e 's/\%$//'`: select lines ending with `%` and deleting the it with sed

Answer (score 0):

If you have the right number of corresponding lines, you don't need any special symbols: use the [`pr`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/pr.1.html) tool to write the data into 2 columns:

```
pr --columns=2 --separator=" " -T <<END
title
another title
other title
one more title
(... continues)
subtitle
other subtitle
some subtitle
one more subtitle
(... continues)
END
```

```
title subtitle
another title other subtitle
other title some subtitle
one more title one more subtitle
(... continues) (... continues)
```

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner awk script would be like

```
awk '/\^/{sub("\\^"," ",$0);a[i++]=$0} /%/{sub("%"," ",$0); print a[NR-i-1],$0}'
```

will produce the output as

```
title  subtitle 
another title  other subtitle 
other title  some subtitle 
one more title  one more subtitle
```

what it does?

`/\^/` matches the patter `^`, the first part of the file.

`sub("\\^"," ",$0)` substitutes `^` with space

`a[i++]=$0` saves the record in array

`/%/` matches the `%` second part of the file.

`print a[NR-i-1],$0` here `NR` is number of records. `NR` keeps increasing hence `NR-i-1` will point to the corresponding line in `a` array